# Tensorflow tf.abs() alternate that can be converted to TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, tensor, tensorrt

I am attempting to convert my Tensorflow frozen model to an NVIDIA TensorRT engine. I have the TensorRT 3 version. TensorRT does not support certain Tensorflow layers/functions, like the `tf.Cast`, etc. 
My model uses the `tf.abs()` function(EDIT: which is in fact supported by TensorRT but not by the UFF parser that is required to build a TensorRT engine), and I am capable of changing the operation before converting the tensorflow checkpoint to a frozen model.

I need to replace `tf.abs()` with an alternate. Therefore, I attempt to do the following numpy operations in Tensorflow.

Numpy:

```
mask = (x<0).astype(np.float32)
mask = 2*mask + 1 #(makes all 1s -1, and all 0s 1)
abs_vals = mask*x
```

Tensorflow:  z is a tensor of zeros, the same shape as x

```
mask = tf.less(x, z)
#convert mask from boolean to integer or float
```

I am unsure how to proceed because I need to convert the boolean mask that tensorflow returns to an integer mask, in order to multiply it to the input, but the `tf.Cast` operation is also not supported by TensorRT.

EDIT: The problem is actually that the UFF parser does not support the `abs` function, while TensorRT does in fact support it. Adding the error log here.

> Using output node generate_output/deprocess/add
>   Converting to UFF graph
>   No. nodes: 361
>   UFF Output written to data/tmp.uff
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_9/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_8/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_7/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_6/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_5/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_4/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_3/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_2/lrelu/mul/x
>   UFFParser: parsing image_tensor
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/load_images/preprocess/mul/y
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/load_images/preprocess/mul
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/load_images/preprocess/sub/y
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/load_images/preprocess/sub
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/input_images/Reshape/shape
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/input_images/Reshape
>   UFFParser: parsing generator/encoder_1/conv/filter
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_1/conv/Conv2D
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_2/lrelu/mul
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_2/lrelu/mul_1/x
>   UFFParser: parsing generate_output/generator/encoder_2/lrelu/Abs
>   UFFParser: Parser error: generate_output/generator/encoder_2/lrelu/Abs: Unary not supported for other non-constant node
>   Failed to parse UFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, UFF conversion doesn't support a lot of operations as of April 2018. This one works and is equivalent to tf.abs():

```
abs_val = tf.maximum( 0, x ) + tf.maximum( 0, -x )
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. TensorRT does support the `abs` function. It is not supported by the UFF parser( mentioned in the EDIT).

Comment: `tf.sqrt` is not supported by UFF either

Comment: Do you know of a list of supported UFF operations?

Comment: Added another solution based on `tf.maximum()` to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I have not come across a list of layers not supported by UFF. But the work around using maximum operation worked great!